# Spring Framework not mapping to my controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an issue with spring framework and I'm not sure if its my eclipse or my jars or me of course...

I have a component scan and sometimes it works sometimes it doesnt when adding packages in the spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema    /beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->


<context:component-scan base-package="com.luis.org.springdemo.mvc" />


<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->


    <mvc:annotation-driven/>


<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Now and in the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org    /xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And these are my controller which some of them map and some dont but the funniest thing was when i alter the  and re-ran the project with the new classes and controllers only the old controllers worked.

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/Customer")
 public class CustomerController{

    @RequestMapping("/forms")
    public String getForm(Model customerModel) {
            customerModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "customer-form";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(@Valid     @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer
            customer, BindingResult theBindingResult) {

        System.out.println("The Customer Last Name is : |" + customer.getLastName()+"|");

        if(theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer-form";
        }else {
            return "customer-result";
        }
    }
 }
```

But this one doesnt

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/osa")
public class ProductController{


@RequestMapping("/forms")
public String createAModel(Model productModel) {
    productModel.addAttribute("product", new Product());    
    return "product-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
public String ProcessModel(@Valid @ModelAttribute("product") Product product, BindingResult 
        theBindingResult){
    if(theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "product-form";
    }else {
        return "process-product";
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.luis.org.springdemo.mvc" />` does the other controller declares in this path?

Comment: Put the url address you put to your browser to invoke ProductController mappings

Comment: @Spara yes Solaski dos that nothing

Comment: As I'm not sure that all your controllers are defining in correct path please test this and tell me what happen : `<context:component-scan base-package="com" />`

Comment: I Will test the suggestion thanks could This have to do with runtime compilation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is was...

My Apache server was apprently caching the latest information and wasn't running none. So I deleted and ran again and worked.